# Sql Server installation error

Tags: sql-server

While i'm installing SQl server 2005 on my system i'm getting an eroor message like this."Setup cannot statrt sqlserver services, just refer hot ststrt services by manually"

I'm using windows seven Beta as OS

Comment: I've not installed 2005 on Win7, but 2008 works fine.

Answer (score 0):

He got it working.
http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/sql-server/windows-7-after-my-first-week/

Perhaps you have a problem with your service accounts.